# Simplifying Data with a for loop (Python)

Tags: python, string, loops, for-loop, simplify

I was trying to simplify the code:

```
            header = []
            header.append(header1)
            header.append(header2)                
            header.append(header3)
            header.append(header4)
            header.append(header5)
            header.append(header6)
```

where:

```
            header1 = str(input.headerOut1)
            header2 = str(input.headerOut2)
            header3 = str(input.headerOut3)
            header4 = str(input.headerOut4)
            header5 = str(input.headerOut5)
            header6 = str(input.headerOut6)
```

I had wanted to use a for loop, like:

```
   headerList = []
   for i in range(6)
          headerList.append(header+i)
```

however, python won't recognize that header+i represents the string header1.  Is there any way to simplify this code or get the for loop to work?  Thank you so much!

Comment: Anybody have an issue with how this question is tagged. Do we need 'for', 'loop', and 'simplify'?

Answer (score 9):

You should really structure your data as a list or a dictionary, like this:

```
input.headerOut[1]
input.headerOut[2]
# etc.
```

which would make this a lot easier, and more Pythonic.  But you can do what you want using `getattr`:

```
headerList = []
for i in range(1, 7):
    header = str(getattr(input, 'headerOut%d' % i))
    headerList.append(header)
```

Comment: ...and if using a list, the first one would be input.headerOut[0].

Comment: agree with @JohnPirie, +1 as there many novel answers but only one that yields code that's easy to understand.

Answer (score 5):

```
header = [str(getattr(input, "headerOut%d" % x)) for x in range(1,7)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the headers in an array and loop through it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`locals`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals) to get the the local scope as a dict:

```
headerList = []
for i in xrange(1, 7):
    headerList.append(locals()['header%s' % (i,)])
```

If possible, though, you should just use the `input` variable directly, as some of the other answers suggested.

Comment: I just had a quick question about this, i have never seen the % (i,) before.  What exactly does it do?  Thanks!

Comment: It's the string formatting operator. Check out the docs here: http://www.python.org/doc/lib/typesseq-strings.html